# How can you avoid clock exploits in Android games?

Tags: android

I need to measure a period of time that can last up to a few hours. I'm assuming the normal way to do this would be something like:

```
Date date = new Date();
...wait some time...
(new Date()).getTime() - date.getTime())
```

But could a user change Android's clock back an hour to cheat the game and make the timespan shorter? Would reading time from an online source be the best solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`new Date()` uses `System.currentTimeMillis()`  which depends on the OS clock - and is subject to change when the user changes the system date and time.

You should use `System.nanoTime()`, which has following properties:

```
/**
 * Returns the current value of the most precise available system
 * timer, in nanoseconds.
 *
 * <p>This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is
 * not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time.
 * The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but
 * arbitrary time (perhaps in the future, so values may be
 * negative).  This method provides nanosecond precision, but not
 * necessarily nanosecond accuracy. No guarantees are made about
 * how frequently values change. Differences in successive calls
 * that span greater than approximately 292 years (2<sup>63</sup>
 * nanoseconds) will not accurately compute elapsed time due to
 * numerical overflow.
 *
 * <p> For example, to measure how long some code takes to execute:
 * <pre>
 *   long startTime = System.nanoTime();
 *   // ... the code being measured ...
 *   long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
 * </pre>
 * 
 * @return The current value of the system timer, in nanoseconds.
 * @since 1.5
 */
public static native long nanoTime();
```

This can not be manipulated by just changing the system date.

Comment: Anyone knows the equivalent for iOS SDK?

Comment: One downside is that the nanoTime will be reset when the cpu is reset. That means you cannot measure the ellapsed time when the phone is turned off.