# What is the iOS equivalent of Java's System.nanoTime()?

Tags: iphone, ios

What is the iOS equivalent of Java's System.nanoTime()?

Basically I just want a simple way to see how many milliseconds (or fractions of ms) that a function takes to execute.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTimeUtils/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001452-CH201-F12326).

```
CFAbsoluteTime before = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
// You code here
CFAbsoluteTime after = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
NSLog(@"duration = %f", after - before);
```

Answer (score 0):

Capture two NSDate objects, one at the start of your function and one at the end.  Use timeIntervalSinceDate: to get an NSTimeInterval value back.  This goes down to "sub-millisecond accuracy" according to the docs.

Comment: See it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686868/how-can-you-avoid-clock-exploits-in-android-games